# gnome-terminal is getting environment variables that other terminals don't

Tags: gnome-terminal

*This is obviously easy to fix, I just want to understand it.  I know Linux, but I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu.*

gnome-terminal is getting environment variables that other terminals (xterm, rxvt-unicode, Linux console) are not.  In particular, gnome-terminal gets `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `ftp_proxy`, `all_proxy`, and all caps versions of those.  Those variables are not in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/environment`.

Comment: What about `/etc/bash.bashrc` (assuming you use bash), and in your home directory, `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.pam_environment` etc.?

Comment: Could it be due to gnome-terminal being default and others not ? Try changing the default terminal and see what happens

Comment: @jpkotta What other terminals don't have these variables set? Terminals in virtual consoles and SSH logins? Are they set in `xterm`?

Comment: Did you do this perhaps? http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-set-proxy-for-terminal-quick.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is gnome-terminal itself that sets these variables. The relevant code resides in gnome-terminal's source, `src/terminal-util.c`, method `terminal_util_add_proxy_env()`. The values are taken from Gnome's settings, and the feature serves the purpose to have Gnome's proxy settings take effect on as many apps/utilities as possible, including console ones.